# Determine how many states the minimal DFA will have

Tags: regular-language

This is the pumping lemma to demonstare that a language is not regular:If L is a regular language,there is a const N such that, for each z in L, with |z|>=N, is possibile to divide z in three sub-strings (uvw=z)such that:

```
1)|uv|<=N;  
2)|v|>=1;  
3)For each k>=0, uv^kw in L.
```

N must be less or equal than the minumum number of states of the DFA accepting L.So to apply the pumping lemma I need to know how many states will have the minimal DFA accepting L.Is there a way to know how many states will have backwards?So is possibile to know the minimal number of states without building the minimal DFA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> N must be less or equal than the minumum number of states of the DFA
>   accepting L

N cannot be less than the number of states in a minimal DFA accepting L; otherwise, the DFA couldn't accept L (if it could, you would have a DFA accepting L smaller than the minimal DFA accepting L, a contradiction). We can safely assume that N is equal to the number of states in the minimal DFA accepting L (such DFAs are unique).

> So to apply the pumping lemma I need to know how many states will have
>   the minimal DFA accepting L

This is not strictly true. In most pumping lemma proofs, it doesn't matter what N actually is; you just have to make sure that the target string satisfies the other properties. It is possible, given a DFA, to determine how many states a minimal DFA will have; however, if you have a DFA, there's no need to bother with the pumping lemma, since you already know L is regular. In fact, determining an N such that there's a minimal DFA with N states accepting L constitutes a valid proof that the language in question is indeed regular.

> So is possibile to know the minimal number of states without building
>   the minimal DFA?

By analyzing the description of the language and using the Myhill-Nerode theorem, it is possible to construct a proof that a language is regular and find the number of states in a minimal DFA, without actually building the minimal DFA (although once you have completed such a proof using Myhill-Nerode, construction of a minimal DFA is a trivial exercise). You can also use Myhill-Nerode as an alternative to the pumping lemma to prove languages aren't regular, by showing a minimal DFA for the language would need to have infinitely many states, a contradiction.

Please let me know whether these observations answer your questions; I will be happy to provide additional clarification.

Comment: Could you provide some source?

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri Proof of the pumping lemma for regular languages, courtesy Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages#Proof_of_the_pumping_lemma . The Myhill-Nerode Theorem, courtesy Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill-Nerode_theorem . These look decently correct, but if you want more academic sources, I would suggest following some of the references on those pages. If you have trouble following the proofs or techniques on those pages, please let me know.